# Orthodox Priest Assignment

Tags: eastern-orthodox, priesthood

Here is a thread answering [how Catholic Priests get assigned to parishes](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-are-catholic-priests-chosen-and-assigned-to-specific-parishes).

How is this done for Orthodox Priests? What is that process and does a newly ordained priest have any say over his assignment? I'm specifically interested in the process for OCA, but Greek and Antiochian information also appreciated.

Say for instance, his wife had strong family ties in a certain state.  Could he request assignment in a certain state?  How likely is that request to be granted?

Comment: My OCA priest put a 'bug' in his bishop's ear about his grandchildren being in another state. Within a year or so, he was transferred closer to his grandchildren.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Clergy | oca.org](http://oca.org/clergy) (Orthodox Church in America), *the rector is appointed by the Diocesan Bishop and cannot leave his parish without the permission of the Bishop.*

Below is the entire section:

> At the head of the parish is its Rector. According to the teachings of
>   the Church, he is the spiritual father and teacher of his flock and
>   the celebrant of the liturgical worship established by the Church. He
>   teaches and edifies the People of God entrusted to his spiritual care
>   "with no partiality" (James 2:1) and sees to it that all activities
>   within the parish serve the religious goals of the Church.
>
> The rector is appointed by the Diocesan Bishop and cannot leave his
>   parish without the permission of the Bishop. No activities in the
>   parish can be initiated without his knowledge, approval, and blessing;
>   neither should he do anything pertaining to the parish without the
>   knowledge of his parishioners and parish organs elected by them, so
>   that always and everywhere there may be unity, mutual trust,
>   cooperation, and love. In conformity with his teaching office, the
>   Rector shall have final authority over the church school. To be free
>   from material preoccupations and wholly committed to his sacred
>   ministry, the priest must be compensated by the parish, the amount of
>   his compensation being clearly agreed upon at the time of his
>   appointment.

See also: [Article X: The Parish](http://oca.org/statute/article-x) | The Statute of the Orthodox Church in America.

**Answering** *Say for instance, his wife had strong family ties in a certain state. Could he request assignment in a certain state? How likely is that request to be granted?*

I would say first step is for the rector to speak with his Bishop.

Answer (score 1):

As FMS said - they can speak to the Bishop.  Certainly preferences can be discussed and can have influence over the ultimate decision.

I go to an Antiochian Orthodox Church - our Priest is from California but serves in Pennsylvania because his wife's family is nearby the area.